# C++: How is static class member implemented?

Tags: c++

Where are static data members stored? Is there some kind of static members table (as in "virtual methods table")?
I've performed an experiment - seems like static members don't affect `sizeof()` at all. Does it mean all references to static members are converted to a fixed address?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The C++ standard doesn't enforce a particular implementation.  But typically static class members will be implemented in a similar fashion to "free" statics.

However, your observation that `sizeof` shouldn't be affected by static members is correct.

Answer (score 4):

Static members in C++ are implemented in exactly the same way as static non-members in both C++ and C. There is no "static member table".